# Solving dust-cleaning robot problem using a* algorithm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, a-star

**Description:** A rectangular area is divided into a matrix A(m, n) with the coordinate origin (1, 1) located at the bottom left corner. At any given time, each cell can be in one of two states: dirty (D) or clean (C). A robot, placed in any cell, can perform one of two groups of actions: (i) move (Move) to one of the four adjacent cells in the directions: left, right, up, or down (see the diagram below), and (ii) perform the dust cleaning operation (Suck) to clean the cell it is in:

- The robot is started, placed in any cell.
- Each time the robot performs one action, the cost incurred for any action (Move, Suck) is equal to 1.
- After each action of the robot, each remaining dirty cell will be assigned a cost of 2.

[image]

**Requirements:** Use the Python language (.ipynb) to write a program that applies the A* algorithm for a dust-cleaning robot to clean dirty cells:

- Allow specifying the size of the matrix A(m, n).
- Allow specifying the number of dirty cells with random positions.
- Display the results: the robot's movement path and the total cost.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I dont know how to caculate the Heuristic. In many web, they said heuristic is the distance from the node to the target. In this problem, robot only moves 4 directions (up, down, left, right) and each time the robot performs one action, the cost incurred for any action (Move, Suck) is equal to 1 and after each action of the robot, each remaining dirty cell will be assigned a cost of 2. It's so strange.

Comment: The phrasing is a little confusing, but if I understand it correctly, you can calculate the total cost by iterating over all turns and summing 1 + 2 * (number of remaining dirty cells).